# How can a directly reference a file that lives in an extension in .vscode/extensions/ in a VS Code task?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have an extension that installs an executable in its folder that I would like to use in a shell task.

```
%HOME/.vscode/extensions/jebbs.plantuml-2.13.11/plantuml.jar
```

but on every update the folder name changes. Is there a way to reference this file?

Comment: can you use https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bbenoist.shell to get the directory name? you can use `${input:xxxx}` fields in the task properties to execute a command with arguments

Comment: Thanks for the input, but definitely no new dependencies for this.